# Problem with Bootstrap 4 Responsive image (imag-fluid)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I created a login in page using a bootstrap grid with an image col-lg-8 and the form col-lg-4. The problem is that when I minimize the screen for smaller devices, the contents are supposed to respond and span 12 each as usual. However, the image always overflows to the top and is cut off. Yes, I used img-fluid on the image.

```
<section class="Form mx-4 h-100">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-80 align-self-center row-eq-height" id="slide-container">

      <div class="col-lg-8 my-auto responsive py-5">
        <img src="Athlete 1.png" alt="This is America" class="img-fluid border-right">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 px-4 my-auto sign-in sign-in-up">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-2 px-0">
              <img src="Athlete 3.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 align-self-center mb-0 px-0">
              <h2>Side-Gym</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 text-center text-secondary mt-2">
            <h4>Members Login</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email..." name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block mt-4 mb-1">Login</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-block" disabled>--------or--------</button>

          <button id="register" type="button" class=" btn-regis btn btn-primary btn-block mt-1 mb-3">Register</button>
          <a href="#" class=" textlink btn-block text-danger text-center">Forgot Password?</a>
          <div class="mb-4 textlink text-center formaer-dropdown">
            <p class="d-inline">Don't have an account? </p>
            <a href="#" class="text-primary" id="register2">Register Here!</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: why there is `.h-100` in the `section` & the container after that? did you use `height` for the `section` or for the wrapper of the `section`? please provide the CSS too, better if you can make a snippet here or somewhere else.

Comment: Its bootstrap 4. h-100 is to make the section and container height span full height of the body. I did this so I can set the row h-80 and then use align-self-center to center the row. The row is the one with a white background and box shadow

Comment: If you gave the wrapper a `height` and didn't use overflow: auto; or scroll then the content will be hidden after that `height`, that's why I asked if you used `height` or not, 

And if the problem is somewhere else, can't say anything about it, because it's just the markup here, need the CSS also.

Comment: I tried using overflow-auto and it didn't work. I don't know if I am using it right. If you can, please access the full code  [link](https://github.com/Isidorev215/SideHustleGym.git) . Thsnks

Comment: Seems like what I told you before is right, you used `height: 100vh;` in `body`, that's why it's behaving like this, when I removed the `height: 100vh;` the whole content was visible, see this screenshot- https://prnt.sc/v2xn57 

Now, if you really need the `height: 100vh;` for `body` add `overflow-y: scroll;` with it at `@media(min-width: 992px)` OR **remove** `height: 100vh;` if you don't need it.

Comment: Why do you need `height: 100vh;` for the `body` anyway? it's working fine without it & also without all the `h-100` & `h-80` classes, see the screen- https://prnt.sc/v2y3qk

Comment: If you really need `height: 100vh;` for the `body` add overflow-y: scroll; with it at @media(min-width: 992px) **AND REMOVE** all the `h-100` & `h-80` classes, otherwise the `overflow-y: scroll;` won't work

Comment: And lemme know if it worked or not

Comment: Yes, it has worked. Thanks. The problem was I did not understand how overflow works. Thanks

Comment: Please accept my answer so other people can understand the problem & its solution better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need `height: 100vh;` for the `body` add `overflow-y: scroll;` with it at `@media(min-width: 992px)` **AND REMOVE** all the `h-100` & `h-80` classes, otherwise the `overflow-y: scroll;` won't work